# Linq - pulling data from two tables - efficiency - alternative linq queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables as part of a messaging system:

```
RECIPIENTS
RecipientId (PK)
RecipientMemberId (FK to user table)
MessageId (FK to message table)
...

MESSAGES
MessageId (PK)
...
```

and these two linq queries:

```
IEnumerable<int> myMessageIds = recipientRepository.Recipients.Where(x => x.RecipientMemberId == User.Identity.GetUserId()).Select(x => x.MessageId);

IEnumerable<Message> inboxMessages = messageRepository.Messages.Where(x => myMessageIds.Contains(x.MessageId));
```

which pull out a user's messages for their inbox.

THE QUESTION:

This works but I have a nasty feeling I'm doing it wrong. Is this inefficient? For fun, what are some alternative linq queries that would produce the same result more efficiently? Any other comments also appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserID();

IEnumerable<Message> inboxMessages = Context
       .Messages
       .Where(x => Context.Recipients
                          .Where(r => r.RecipientMemberId == userId)
                          .Any(r => x.MessageId == r.MessageId));
```

But Even more so, you **should** have Navigation Properties on Recipient and Message.

```
public class Recipient
{
    .....
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } // If this is your PK

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } // navigational Property to Messages
}
```

and your Message:

```
public class Message
{
    .....
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } // If this is your PK

    public int RecipientId { get; set; } // This would be FK
    public virtual Recipient Recipient { get; set; } // navigational property back to Recipient
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var recipient = Context.Recipients
                       .Where(x => x.RecipientMemberId == userId)
                       .FirstOrDefault()

var messages = recipient.Messages.ToList();
```

Note, this will make 2 calls to the database, one when you get the recipient. And another when you access the virtual messages property.

To optimize this, you can tell EF to "`Include`"  a navigational property in its query, which will then do a join.

E.g.

```
var recipient = Context.Recipients
                       .Include(x => x.Messages)
                       .Where(x => x.RecipientMemberId == userId)
                       .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in what you are doing. As long as you are querying a table using a primary key, an index or a foreign key it is perfectly optimized by the RDMS.

In your case:

```
IEnumerable<int> myMessageIds 
      = recipientRepository.Recipients
        .Where(x => x.RecipientMemberId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
        .Select(x => x.MessageId);
```

you are using the RecipientMemberId which is a foreign key. You can rewrite the same query as follow if you want, using linq instead of lambda expressions:

```
var myMessageIds = from recipient in recipientRepository.Recipients
                  let userId = User.Identity.GetUserId() // done only once
                  where recipient.RecipientMemberId == userId
                  select recipient.MessageId;
```

Same thing for your second query:

```
var inboxMessages = from message in messageRepository.Messages
                  where myMessageIds.Contains(message.MessageId)
                  select message;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can often access related data via a navigation property. If you created your tables via code first they would look something like this :

```
public class Recipient 
{
     public int RecipientId { get; set; }
     public virtual Icollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
     // etc
}

 public class Message 
 {
     public int MessageId { get; set; }
     public virtual Recipient Recipient { get; set; }
     // etc
}
```

Similar properties would be generated by an edmx or dbml file.

```
IEnumerable<Message> myMessages = recipientRepository.Recipients.Where(x => x.RecipientMemberId == User.Identity.GetUserId()).SingleOrDefault().Messages;
```